# How to implement a Garbage Collection function for SQLITE with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, garbage-collection

Is there some way to create garbage collection function that clean out old or expired data stored in SQLITE database?

I am using it to create a session storage database , and I want the old expired sessions to be deleted. so i need some sort of garbage collection function that run periodically that auto delete these expired sessions which are wasting space.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from running a simple DELETE query filtered by some date field?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "old"/"expired"?

Comment: edited. maybe more clear now? sorry my english not that good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Just call the DELETE query when the condition (old or expired) is met.